# Using new credentials for AWS ECR get-login

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I'm already logged in to one ECR, but I want to change the credentials I am using to log in to a new ECR. But every time I call `aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region region` it just logs in to the previous ECR.

How can I change the credentials it is using to make a new log in on the same machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a default profile setup in your .awsconfig? If so, add another profile and reference it with `aws ecr get-login --profile <new>`. Or specify in the cmd line the actual AWS account credentials you want to generate the ECV login for.

edit
You have `.aws/config` and `.aws/credentials`

```
/credentials


[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKASFDSDFSAF
aws_secret_access_key=dfgfdgdfg

[h]
aws_access_key_id=AKASFDSDFSAF
aws_secret_access_key=dsfdgfdg

[e]
aws_access_key_id=AKTRYUTRYTR
aws_secret_access_key=asfdiasjop



/config


[default]
output=json
region=eu-west-2

[profile h]
output=json
region=eu-west-2

[profile e]
output=json
region=eu-west-2
```

And reference these with `--profile h`, `--profile e`, and no profile (`default`)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup new profile by replacing your access key and secret key in `aws configure` command. The access key and security key can be setup under My Security Credentials.

```
$ aws configure
    AWS Access Key ID [None]: your_access_key
    AWS Secret Access Key [None]: your_secret_key
    Default region name [None]: repository_region
    Default output format [None]: optional
```